# How to get multiple values from a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, set, unique-values

I have a list of records from a column, the list is named as dates. I am trying to get different dates out of the list. The list have many repetitive dates, such as 1/1/2010,1/1/2010, …. but there are different dates too. 
But if i use:

```
for date in dates: ....
```

it's repeating the loop for every single date(no matter if it is the same or not), not different dates. How could I tell it to do:

```
for differentdate in dates:...
```

The language is Python!!

Comment: You forgot to tell us which programming language you're using. This is Python, right?

Comment: This is Python, right? @Neal might as well be, it's Python :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for date in set(dates):
```

`set()` makes a collection out of the unique elements in another collection. Note: this may not preserve the order of the original list, so if you require that order to be preserved, go with @GregHewgill's answer.

Comment: Note that this destroys ordering, i.e. you get the items in an undetermined order (well, it's deterministic, but you almost never know/care about some of the things that influence it, so it might as well be random). It's possible to retain order and filter dupes, but that requires about 5 lines more.

Comment: @delnan: I added a note, Greg has addressed this with groupby

Comment: set(dates) works perfectly for me!! thank you so much. i knew it would be a minor change of codes

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module to group by the dates. For example:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ["aaa", "bbb", "bbb", "ccc"]
>>> for k, g in itertools.groupby(a):
...   print(k)
... 
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

This preserves the original order of the elements in `a` (which could be important for you). Inside the loop, `g` is a generator that produces a sequence containing each element with that key. See the documentation for [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for more information.

Comment: Typo in the URL. Also, this won't eliminate the dupe in `['a', 'b', 'a']`, which is propably what OP wants (you can `.sort()` to fix that though).

Comment: groupby seems interesting, but order does not matter to me, I just want values.Tks @delnan: u r right, and .sort() is enough to solve the order problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following:

```
def uniqueItems(seq, key=None, reverse=False):
    "Returns a list of unique items in (customizable) order"
    seq = list(set(seq))
    seq.sort(key=key, reverse=reverse)

def uniqueItems(seq):
    "Generator - return unique items in original order of first occurrence"
    seen = set()
    for item in seq:
        if item not in seq:
            yield item
            seen.add(item)
```

can be used as

```
for date in uniqueItems(dates):
    # do something with date
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If preserving order *was* important, the following generator function derived from a comment by Alex Martelli about the [Remove duplicates from a sequence](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52560) ActiveState recipe would work (and should also be relatively fast based to these [bench-marks](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark) which included the original dictionary-based, non-generator Martelli exemplar):

```
dates = ["1/1/2010", "1/3/2010", "1/3/2010", "1/7/2010"]

def unique(seq, idfun=lambda x: x):
    seen = set()
    for item in seq:
        marker = idfun(item)
        if marker not in seen:
            seen.add(marker)
            yield item

for date in unique(dates):
    print date

# 1/1/2010
# 1/3/2010
# 1/7/2010
```

Another nice feature is that it's fairly flexible and can be adapted to other data structures by providing a custom `idfun` to use to retrieve the datum to be compared.